# UWP KeyboardAccelerator of functions

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I know how to add `KeyboardAccelerators` to `UIElement`s, but can they exist without a `UIElement`? I just want the Keyboard combo to activate a function.

For example, I want the user to trigger a function called `moveFiveSecsAhead()` when pressing right and `moveFiveSecsBack()` when pressing left.

How can I achieve that? One possible solution I can think of is to add two invisible buttons. But is there an easier solution?

---Update---

So I added this piece of code to my [control](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/MediaControl.xaml.cs), and it seems that it works well in the debug mode but causes crash in release mode. Why is that?

```
var left = new KeyboardAccelerator() { Key = Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left };
left.Invoked += (sender, args) => MediaHelper.Position = Math.Max(MediaHelper.Position - 5, 0);
var right = new KeyboardAccelerator() { Key = Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right };
right.Invoked += (sender, args) => MediaHelper.Position = Math.Min(MediaHelper.Position + 5, CurrentMusic.Duration);
this.KeyboardAccelerators.Add(left);
this.KeyboardAccelerators.Add(right);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your keyboard accelerators to the `Page` you are using and no need for adding two invisible buttons.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var accelerator = new KeyboardAccelerator() { Key = , Modifiers= };
        accelerator.Invoked += moveFiveSecsBack;
        var accelerator1 = new KeyboardAccelerator() { Key = , Modifiers = };
        accelerator.Invoked += moveFiveSecsAhead;
        this.KeyboardAccelerators.Add(accelerator);
        this.KeyboardAccelerators.Add(accelerator1);
    }
    private void moveFiveSecsBack(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    private void moveFiveSecsAhead(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Could you take a look at the update area? It causes crash.

Comment: Have you able to right any logs ? Can you do exception handling and find what exception it through’s by showing in message dialog?

Comment: Wait there is another problem with this. My control now has a tooltip "left" with this piece of code. And I could not remove it by setting the tooltip to null. Any ideas on how to remove the tooltip?

Comment: Control the tooltip behavior by using the `KeyboardAcceleratorPlacementMode` property, which accepts two values: `Auto` or `Hidden`. use hidden to hide the `ToolTip`